# Using a stateful, pipe and filter application within the OSGi framework with declarative services

Tags: java, osgi, osgi-bundle

i have an existing 'pipe-and-filter' application which i am converting to bundles to work within the osgi framework.  this application uses a pipe manager class which reads in xml config files and dynamically build pipes with custom filter combinations / configurations based on the xml file input.

to accomplish this in the osgi framework with declarative services, my thought process is simple - all possible filter services will have to be referenced (injected) into the pipe manager service bundle so that it may dynamically build whatever pipe is requested.  but this now begs the question, if the scr doesn't start bundles until all referenced dependency services are available, won't this mean that if any of the filter bundles will not start (or shuts down), the entire pipe manager service will shutdown?

Additionally, are there special considerations that need to be taken into account for creating services within osgi that are stateful (initialized, started, stopped, etc.)?

Comment: What you are trying to do is to create kind of a framework. This is not trivial. Some time ago I created a prototype of a reactive framework similar to apache camel. Not sure if it is near enough you case but maybe it can help as a reference: https://github.com/apache/karaf-reactive-components

Answer (score 0):

Yes, services will shutdown when the required services are or become not available. But you can mark service references as optional. This way your main "pipe manager service" stays online while your filter services come and go. But you have to deal with the case where the referenced services might not be available. Maybe that's even desired to plug-in filters when actually needed.

There are no additional special considerations with stateful services, which are running in OSGi. All the problems of having stateful services are still the same.